# How to reload function datatables with new parameter in ajax when Selected value in Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I've this https://jsfiddle.net/cubmf71z/44/ ..

I want to reload function data_list with new parameter in ajax in same function data_list when i'm select or unselect in multiple ajax :

```
$(".select2-multiple").on("select2:select", function (c) {
```

I was try $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();  isnt working . i dont know how to put it .

in html

```
<input type="text" id="type">
```

in js

```
(function($){
  $('.select2-multiple').select2();
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function data_list() {

    var type = $('#type').val();    

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "scrollY": "200px",
        "paging": true
    /*"ajax": {
                                "url": "https://",
                    dataSrc: function ( json ) {
                        if ( json.status === 'failed' ) {
                            return [];
                        }
                    return json.data;
                    }
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "appl" },
                { "data": "BankDates" },
                { "data": "State" },
                { "data": "cash" },
                { "data": "cheque" }
            ],

            columnDefs: [ 
                {  width: 100, targets: 0 },
                { "className": "text-center", width: 100, targets: 1 },
                { "className": "text-center", width: 100, targets: 2 },
                { "className": "dt-body-right", width: 100, targets: 3 },
                { "className": "dt-body-right", width: 100, targets: 4 }
            ]


     */
    } );

            $(".select2-multiple").on("select2:select", function (c) {
                c.preventDefault();
                var datas = c.params.data.id;
                alert(datas);
                //-> i update here parameter type $('#type').val('bank_date');
       //i want to call call/reload function data_list datatables with new ajax url and parameter
                var column = table.column(datas); 
                column.visible( ! column.visible() );
            });

            $(".select2-multiple").on("select2:unselect", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();         
                var data = e.params.data.id;
                alert(data);    
                var column = table.column(data); 
                column.visible( ! column.visible() );
            });

} );
```

Maybe you know how to call the function with another way ? or i'm wrong to put it ?
Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at using the data section of your ajax call to capture the select boxes values and passing that to the server?

Comment: yes. but i dont know in datatables . i using this var type = $('#type').val(); and <input id="type" value=""> when selected i change this 
 $('#type').val('bank_date'); to change the parameter . wait .. i update my code

Comment: i updated my code in question @Bindrid

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!--<!DOCTYPE html>-->
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Simple Client Side</title>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
                <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
                <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/blockui.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                            "processing": true,
                            "serverSide": false,
                            rowId: "employeeId",
                            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) { },
                            "columns": [
                                { "data": "first_name" },
                                { "data": "last_name"},
                                { "data": "position" },
                                { "data": "office" },
                                { "data": "extn" },
                                { "data": "start_date" },
                                { "data": "salary" }
                            ],
                            "select": "multi",
                            "lengthMenu": [5, [10, 15, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, "All"]],
                            "pageLength": 5,
                            "ajax": {
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "wsSample.asmx/GetAllEmployees",
                                type: "Post",
                                data: function (parms) {
                                    data = $("#selMy").val();

                                    return parms
                                },
                                dataSrc: "d"
                            },
                            order: [[0, 'asc']]
                        });
                        $("#selMy").select2().change(function () {
                            table.ajax.reload();
                        })
                    });

                </script>

            </head>
                <body>

                    <table class="display" id="example" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First</th>
                                <th>Last</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Start date</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr class="searchRow">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                <th>Phone</th>
                                <th>Start date</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    <select id="selMy" style="width:200px" multiple><option value="a">a</option>
                        <option value="b">b</option>
                        <option value="c">c</option>
                        <option value="d">d</option>
                    </select>

                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: not to get lost in it all, the point is that when the table.ajax.reload is called, the data function is call and you can stuff what ever parameters you need to go back to the server

Comment: yes, but my parameter doesnt change. and my ajax and your ajax is different

Comment: sorry @Bindrid Thanks , wait im still trying

Comment: when i want to change into get ? how ?

Comment: I updated the code above where the on change event on the select box triggers the ajax reload.  The data section will take the selected items and put them in the parameters that get sent to the server.

Comment: oke . if i post more than one parameter .. using data var ? data = $("#selMy").val(); @Bindrid

Comment: On a multi select, data in this context will always be an array of selected values. If there are no selected values, it will be an empty array.

Comment: i'm using php . so when the url get the param post . what should the name ?  $_POST['selMy'] or $_POST['data'] .... because i var_dump($_POST['data']) no value ?? @Bindrid

Comment: I don't know much about PHP (I have worked with c# and java back ends) put $_POST is a post, you need to include that in your ajax definition. By default, ajax is a get.

Comment: My code includes a type: "post" but I did not see that in yours